# Select objects from table A that is associated to all selected objects from Table B by SQL

Tags: sql

Sorry for the long title but I have the following situation:

**Table 1**

```
id  |  title
---------------
1   |  object 1
2   |  object 2
3   |  object 3
```

**Table 2**

```
id  |  title
---------------
1   |  item 1
2   |  item 2
3   |  item 3
```

**Table 3 (n-m association)**

```
id  |  object_id  |  item_id
------------------------------
1   |  1          |  1
2   |  1          |  2
3   |  2          |  1
4   |  2          |  2
5   |  2          |  3
6   |  3          |  2
7   |  3          |  3
```

Now I want to get all objects from table 1 that a are associated to item 2 **AND** item 3.

The result should be object 2 and object 3.

But I have no clue how the SQL query should look like.

Any help?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and straight-forward. You want t1 rows the ID of which is both related to item 1 and item 2:

```
select *
from t1
where id in (select object_id from t3 where item_id = (select id from t2 where title = 'item 1'))
  and id in (select object_id from t3 where item_id = (select id from t2 where title = 'item 2'));
```

Comment: Both answers (@sagi + @Thorsten Kettner) work for me (but indeed I needed to add distinct like `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.item_id) = 2` to the above query). But this answer here seems to have the better performance, though. While the above query took about 100ms in a bunch of runs this query took around 60ms so I selected this as the "correct" answer. Thanks in any case!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT t.title
FROM Table1 t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table3 s
             WHERE t.id = s.object_id
              AND s.item_id in(2,3)
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Comment: @jarlh there are no groups, just a constant `1`, same as `select count(*) from x`

Comment: @jarlh Group by what?.. Just need to check the query returns two rows

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @sagi should it be  `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.item_id) = 2` ?

Comment: From the sample data it doesn't look like it could contain duplicates though.. @ErgestBasha