# Select objects from Table A that are associated to objects in Table B ordered by matching count

Tags: sql

This is an addition to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75285895/select-objects-from-table-a-that-is-associated-to-all-selected-objects-from-tabl):

I want to get all objects from table 1 that a have associations to item 2 or item 3, ordered by the count of matching associations.

So the result should be a list like: object 2 (2 matches), object 3 (2 matches), object 1 (1 match).

What must the SQL look like to get the results ordered?

**Table 1**

```
id  |  title
---------------
1   |  object 1
2   |  object 2
3   |  object 3
```

**Table 2**

```
id  |  title
---------------
1   |  item 1
2   |  item 2
3   |  item 3
```

**Table 3 (n-m association)**

```
id  |  object_id  |  item_id
------------------------------
1   |  1          |  1
2   |  1          |  2
3   |  2          |  1
4   |  2          |  2
5   |  2          |  3
6   |  3          |  2
7   |  3          |  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Join Table1 with Table3 and aggregate as the following:

```
select T1.id, T1.title, count(*) matches
from table1 T1 join table3 T3
on T1.id = T3.object_id
where T3.item_id in (2, 3)
group by T1.id, T1.title
order by matches, T1.id
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/i2dQR8aR)